# RL-TCPnet crash when send and get at the same time

Tags: microcontroller, c, keil, lpc, network-interface

I'm working on a web service with RL-ARM libraries. I want to send some parameters with AJAX as .cgx file and at the same time I want to create a socket and then send a lot of data to the destination.

The problem that is when my microcontroller wants to do these two tasks at the same time; it crashes. I discovered with debug that the process stops at this function: `main_TcpNet();`.

I also realized the process doesn't stop in these functions:

`U16 cgi_func (U8 *env, U8 *buf, U16 buflen, U32 *pcgi){}`

and

`void cgi_process_data (U8 code, U8 *dat, U16 len) {}`

I'm beyond confused because of I don't know what should I do to fix it .

The microcontroller is: [LPC1768](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf)
The network IC is: [DP83848VV](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83848c.pdf)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wrong stack exchange

Comment: Microcontroller firmware trouble-shooting _is_ on-topic here but there's no telling what could be the problem here, since not enough code nor details are provided. Generally, don't stare yourself blind on symptoms, but rather try to find the reason why the symptoms are there. There's no root cause "the MCU doesn't stop in function x" or "the MCU doesn't execute function x" - those are symptoms of some underlying bug.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Wrong close reason, this should be closed as unclear but it is not off-topic. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: It's software. It should be asked in a software sub.